# Prettier doubling indentation on github despite looking ok locally

Tags: github, indentation, prettier

I'm using prettier with PyCharm with the following settings:

```
{
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 80,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "proseWrap": "always",
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "requireConfig": false,
    "useTabs": true,
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
    "semi": true
}
```

Here's some indented example:

```
function myFunction(x) {
    if (x) {
        console.log('1');
    } else {
        console.log('0');
    }
}
```

Before formatting with prettier, if pushed to remote, it looks fine:

[image: before]

After reformatting with prettier, the indentation still looks the same locally as well as when pasted here:

[image: local]

However, this is how it looks on github:

[image: after]